# VS 2010 Professional Only Works From Remote Desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 on my laptop (Win 7).
Whenever I start it, it crashes immediately without giving any error.

- devenv /log has no error[image: devenv /log - No Error]
- devenv /safemode crashes
- deleted %appdata%/microsoft/visualstudios/10.0/ folder and started visual studio again but still no use
- Re-installed visual studio a couple of times
- Re-installed the .NET framework 4, 4.5 and 4 Multi-targeting pack
- Rebooted machine after every step :)
- Has older visual studio 2005 which works just fine. (yeah, 2005!)

[image]

### From Remote desktop and On Screenshare

- When I connect to my laptop from some other machine using remote desktop it starts working and on disconnect it crashes immediately
- When I start it in screenshare (some windows client, not sure which client) it starts and crashes immediately when screenshare is stopped

How to make this work right?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer; but I suggest you upgrade your display drivers, or switch them to the most basic driver you can for your system. (Or switch them to drivers that are WHQL certified).  It sounds like a display driver issue. You should also attempt to load Visual Studio in Windows Safe Mode (Restart Windows in Safe Mode).

Comment: Okay, let me try, will reply after trying that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Log into machine via remote desktop
- Start visual studio
- Go Tools > Options > Environment > General > Visual Experience
- Uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience on client performance"
  [image]
- Ok, done!
- Restart visual studio, should work fine now without remote desktop!

Answer (score 4):

This sounds an awful lot like it is being triggered by Aero, perhaps as a result of a video driver issue as George suggests. When enabled, the rendering pipeline for window chrome changes significantly, and may be flushing out bugs in either Visual Studio, WPF or the video drivers.

You can test this fairly easily: just disable Aero system-wide, and see if the crashes persist. You can find a guide to doing this here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-aero-on-windows-vista/ - you can also just kill the DWM service directly, as described in [How to quickly enable\disable Aero in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/209676/how-to-quickly-enable-disable-aero-in-windows-7).

If that *works*, then you should be able to disable it for *just VS* by opening the program's compatibility settings and checking "Disable desktop composition".

Alternately, hope that George's suggestion to update your drivers makes this go away.

#### Related:

- [Visual Studio Crash when using Desktop Composition (Aero)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/562280/visual-studio-crash-when-using-desktop-composition-aero)

Comment: I had forgotten about Aero. Great call.

Comment: FWIW, I once had a set of Nvidia drivers that would crash SSMS if I moved the mouse "wrong" over the output grid control. Sometimes, it would bring down the whole machine. Very, very annoying.

Comment: Killed dwm and disabled aero, still no luck. and I got Nvidia drivers too.

Comment: Got it guys!
Started visual studio from remote desktop
Tools > Options > Environment > General > Visual Experience
Uncheck the checkbox "Automatically adjust visual experience on client performance"
Restarted visual studio > works
Started aero and dwm and restart visual studio > still works

Thanks guys!

Comment: You should post that as an answer, @Kiran!